# Is there a way to pass a brace enclosed list to variadic templates?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, parameter-passing, function-templates

I would like to pass a variable list of objects to be passed to a template function as a series of brace enclosed initializers.

So something like this:

```cpp
enum class E { a, b, c };

template <typename T>
struct Info
{
    template <typename U>
    Info(E e, U u)
        : e(e)
        , size(sizeof(u))
    {}

    E e;
    size_t size;
};

template <typename...Ts>
void fn(Info<Ts>&&...args) { }

int f() {
    fn({ E::a, 5 });
}
```

If I replace the above with concrete types, the  brace enclosed initializers does work:

```cpp
enum class E { a, b, c };

struct InfoBase { E e; int size; };

void f1(InfoBase&& a, InfoBase&& b) { }

void f() {
    f1({ E::a, 4 }, { E::b, 6 });
}
```

But replacing `f1` with the following fails:

```
void f1() { }

template <typename...Ts>
void f1(InfoBase&& a, Ts&&...args)
{
    f1(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
}
```

Presumably because it's can't infer `Ts`?

Error messages are:

```
<source>: In function 'void f()':
<source>:22:7: error: no matching function for call to 'f1(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   22 |     f1( { E::a, 4 }, { E::b, 6 } );
      |     ~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:16:6: note: candidate: 'void f1(InfoBase&&, Ts&& ...) [with Ts = {}]'
   16 | void f1(InfoBase&& a, Ts&&...args) {
      |      ^~
<source>:16:6: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
<source>:14:6: note: candidate: 'void f1()'
   14 | void f1() { }
      |      ^~
<source>:14:6: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

I'm thinking that because `Ts` has no concrete type to bind to, it just fails, even though that information is available later in the call tree. Is that correct?

Is what I'm attempting just not possible?

Comment: `{ E::a, 4 }` doesn't have a type, so none can be deduced.

Comment: Workaround `f1( { E::a, 4 }, InfoBase{ E::b, 6 } );` - but what's wrong with your original where you have two `InfoBase` arguments?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, because this is a sample.  I'm going to have a variable number of `InfoBase` arguments., and I don't want to constantly state the type in the initialization list.

Comment: Ok, `void f1(std::initializer_list<InfoBase> args)` ? It can be called with `f1({{E::a, 4}, {E::b, 6}});` - would that be an option?

Comment: @TedLyngmo, though that is a good idea, unfortunately this is not going to work as I try to progress to the first incarnation shown above where each type is slightly different.

Comment: Hmm, ok, then I think specifying the actual type for each argument is the best (maybe only) option.

Comment: I'm thinking I might be able to do this, but I have to unwrap the items and parse them as groups. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the plain `{}`, has no type, it can not be used in the template type deduction.

From what I understood, that you're trying to achieve, I propose the following

```
template <typename T, typename...Ts>
void fn(E e, T&& val, Ts&&...args)
{
    Info<T> ob{ e, std::forward<T>(val) };  // do something with ob
    // ....

    if constexpr (sizeof...(args) == 1u) {
        std::cout << "At least required two args!\n";
        // other error msgs or handling
    }
    else if constexpr (sizeof...(args)) {   
        fn(std::forward<Ts>(args)...); // process what left by recursive calls
    }
}
```

Now pass/ call the function as

```
fn(E::a, 4, E::b, 6);
```

[See a demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1TjW4fr6s)

Comment: Yeah, this is where I was heading.

Comment: As I didn't want to have explicit calls in the initialization, this seems to be best.